# Getting Null returned in Property Transfer in SoapUI

Tags: xpath, properties, null, soapui, transfer

I am getting null returned, I am going in circles, fiddling pointlessly. I have it working with an older version of the WSDL, trying to get it going with a newer version, generated from Jax-WS, was using Axis. There have been some minor changes.
I want to get the value "6001305" from Response. 
I am hoping someone will spot the problem. I am pretty sure the Target is fine, it's pretty simple. I am not very fluent at all.

Response I am working with:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:requestPortResponse xmlns:ns2="http://transferobjects.abc.abc.org">
         <return so="6001305" state="Awaiting Response">
            <success>true</success>
         </return>
      </ns2:requestPortResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My setup for Source (Property Response, Path Language XPath)

```
declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://abc.abc.org/api/serviceorder';
declare namespace ns2='http://transferobjects.abc.abc.org';
//ns2:requestPortResponse/return/so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `@` before your `so` to indicate that it's an attribute. So your whole line should be

```
//ns2:requestPortResponse/return/@so
```

Comment: OMG! That worked immediately. Why doesn't anything anywhere tell me I need an @? SoapUI documentation is really very sparse. Also, in my older WSDL version it didn't appear to be required. You the man, upvoted as much as I can.

Comment: Soz, didn't realise I could do that. I just about want to have your children, you saved me a bucket of time.

Comment: Now you know. That should guarantee you a great future at SO.

Answer (score 1):

The @zx485 answer output :

```
so="6001305"
```

Mine:

```
6001305
```

Try this :

```
string(//ns2:requestPortResponse/return/@so)
```